# unexplained behavior of GetOpenFileName() on windows 7 64 bit OS

Tags: c++, winapi

im really struggling here to understand why the following function blocks my entire IEXPLORER process whenever it's the next command to be processed. im almost sure it's something related to the hwndOwner varible. during one of my diggings in the callstack of the ntdll.dll. i noticed these 2 lines :

```
ntdll.dll!_ZwWaitForMultipleObjects@20()  + 0x15 bytes  
ntdll.dll!_ZwWaitForMultipleObjects@20()  + 0x15 bytes
```

one of my "educated" guesses is that a deadlock might have been appeared, but i dont exatclly have the tools and knowledge to understand what/who actually caused it.
as the topic says it, on OS 32 bit win7 based, this doesn't happen.
i couldn't find any line in my code that actually locks that particular hwnd and might have caused a deadlock or a pre-lock.

```
EXPORTFILENAME ofn;
        ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
        ofn.hwndOwner       = m_hWnd;
        ofn.lStructSize     = sizeof(OPENFILENAME);
        ofn.Flags           = OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT | OFN_ENABLESIZING | OFN_EXPLORER | OFN_NOREADONLYRETURN | ((DVDBURN == (eType & DVDBURN)) ? (/*OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT |*/ /*OFN_ENABLEINCLUDENOTIFY |*/ OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_ENABLETEMPLATE | OFN_ENABLEHOOK) : 0);
        ofn.nFilterIndex    = 1;
        ofn.lpstrTitle      = Title;
        ofn.lpstrFilter     = szFilter;
        ofn.lpstrFile       = szResult; 
        ofn.nMaxFile        = MAX_PATH;
        ofn.lpstrDefExt     = szFilter + wcslen(szFilter) + 1; // UGH..
        if(DVDBURN == (eType & DVDBURN)) {
            ofn.lpfnHook        = DVDSelectorProc;
            ofn.lpTemplateName  = MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DLG_EXPORTER_BURNNER);
            ofn.hInstance       = (HINSTANCE)&__ImageBase;
        }
        ofn.pExporter       = this;

        if(0 == (eType & OPENFILE)) {
            if( ::GetSaveFileName(&ofn))
                VerifyTargetFileName(szResult, szResultOut);
            else {
                SetLastError(CommDlgExtendedError());
                goto GracefulExit;
            }
        } else {
            ATLTRACE("GFX ThreadId = %u\r\n", GetCurrentThreadId());
            if( ::GetOpenFileName(&ofn))
                VerifyTargetFileName(szResult, szResultOut);
            else {
                SetLastError(CommDlgExtendedError());
                goto GracefulExit;
            }
        }
```

when EXPORTFILENAME =

```
    struct EXPORTFILENAME : OPENFILENAME {
        CVMNExporter*   pExporter;
        WCHAR           szResultBurningDrive[128];
    };
```

---

#### EDIT:

I also tried to discard the owner HWND by inserting 0/NULL. that didn't work either..

Comment: I for one don't exactly know what this means: "the following function blocks my entire IEXPLORER process whenever it's the next command to be processed". Do you mean that whenever someone tries to open a file, IE hangs? Also, I think that posting a complete (or at least more complete) stack trace than just two entries from who-knows-what part of the stack trace will be more helpful to people who might be willing to take a look. Finally, you might want to explain a bit about your application and the context that this code is called from.

Comment: Do you have any shell extensions installed? Can you try running this on a "clean" install of Windows (e.g., on a virtual machine)?

Comment: will try next week(weekend), problem is that i've not seen that code ever before and im simply trying to figure out what the developer prior me has done. but i managed to figure out that the m_hwnd HWND isn't the right HWND and actually holds the hidden window HWND. as my class implements the IObjectWithSite interface, during the runtime, SetSite() is called and then uses Create(0) from the atlWin.h to create a silent window. i dont know why it's done but gotta figure it out.